# How do I do a Dir.glob but exclude directories?

Tags: ruby

If I wanted to get all of the CSS and JavaScript files

```
Dir.glob("dir/**/*.{css,js})
```

gives me stuff I don't want if there's a folder named `stupidfolder.js`. I would just change the name of the folder, but I can't.

Comment: You don't explain what you're trying to do, but it appears you want to descend into a directory looking for specific files. And, if so, Ruby's [Find](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/find/rdoc/Find.html) class is a great tool. Its startup speed is faster and it is more scalable than using `Dir.glob` which will walk the hierarchy first, gathering a list, then return an array of everything found. Find's documentation shows how to `prune` directories.

Comment: Yes I am trying to descend into a directory to get the paths to all the .css and .js files, but there happen to be some bad folder names that end in .js so I would like these to be excluded. I didn't know about Find so I will check that out.

Comment: It's a minor step to weed out folders, whatever the name. `File.directory?('path/to/folder_or_file')` will tell you. Again, the documentation specifically demonstrates how to do that.

Answer (score 13):

You can't do that with `Dir.glob`. You have to reject those entries explicitly.

```
only_files = Dir.glob('*').reject do |path|
  File.directory?(path)
end
```

Answer (score 5):

It may be an exaggeration for your problem, but `rake` defines a class `FileList`. You could replace `Dir.glob` with this class:

```
require 'rake'
filelist = FileList.new("dir/**/*.{css,js}")
filelist.exclude('**/stupidfolder.js')
filelist.each do |file|
   #... 
end
```

Comment: I like this answer, because its something that a Rakefile should be able to do. Just an alternative answer, not a round-about answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with `Dir.entries`

```
Dir.entries('../directoryname').reject { |f| File.directory?(f) }
```